# parallel.invoke transaction scope entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactionscope

In my EF4 program, I have an Applicant and Application table. Multiple instances of the program runs periodically to create application for applicants based on some business logic. In Application table I cannot have more than one Submitted/BeingSubmitted records for an Applicant.

So here's the piece of code which checks if there's an Submitted/BeingSubmitted application and inserts it. It is run inside a foreach loop for a list of Applicants.

```
public Application SaveApplication(Int32 applicantId)
    {
        using (TransactionScope txScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            if (ApplicantHasPendingApplication(applicantId))
                return null;

            Application app = null;
            try
            {
                app = new Application()
                {
                    // Create the object...
                };

                _unitOfWork.DisclosureApplications.Add(app);
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
                _unitOfWork.Refresh(app); // We save and refresh it to get the Id.

                txScope.Complete();
            }
            catch (UpdateException ex)
            {
                // We get an Update exception here when multiple instances tries to insert Application.
            }

            return app;
        }
    }
```

Above piece of code prevents insertion of duplicate records apart from the fact that it throws UpdateException while running multiple instances of the program. If I swallow that exception and carry on then everything is fine.

However, I tried to test/run above code in parallel but it inserts duplicate records in database.

```
Parallel.Invoke(
            () => CreateApplications("Parallel Instance 1"),
            () => CreateApplications("Parallel Instance 2"));

private void CreateApplications(String dummyInstanceName)
{
   var unitOfWork = new SqlUnitOfWork();
   var applicants = unitOfWork.Applicants.FindAll().Take(100).ToList();

   var facade = new ProviderFacade(unitOfWork, new Log4NetLogger(dummyInstanceName));

   foreach (Applicant applicant in applicants)
            {
                facade.ApplicationProvider.SaveApplication(applicant.applicantID);
            }
}
```

In above piece of code, it throws UpdateException and inserts multiple Application row for an Applicant.

Note that, the table only has a surrogate primary key and no other unique constraints.

My question is: Why the TransactionScope inserts duplicate rows by running it in Parallel.Invoke but not when I fire off multiple instances of the program? What would be a sound approach achieving it?

Update: The ctor of SqlUnitOfWork is

```
public SqlUnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new MyEntities();
    }
```

The ctor of MyEntities is generated by EF -

```
    public const string ConnectionString = "name=Entities";
    public const string ContainerName = "Entities";

    public TPIEntities() : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you call facade.ApplicationProvider.SaveApplication, what _unitOfWork is being used?  I'm not seeing how the SqlUnitOfWork created in CreateApplications is getting passed through there.  If your two instances of CreateApplications end up effectively using the same SqlUnitOfWork, that could be related to your issue.

Comment: Please see the update. Also added the line where I create the facade. As I do a _new_ SqlUnitOfWork inside CreateApplications, what's the possibility of same UnitOfWork being used across the parallel method calls? (I'm new to parallel programming.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic race condition. Both transactions check to see if a pre-existing `Application` exists. Both find that there is none. Then, both try to insert.

You need to synchronize your checking, either by locking in the application or by taking a SQL Server `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` when checking whether the `Application` exists.

Comment: I'm using EF here, so how do I tell Sql Server to do UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK?

Comment: You need to use ExecuteStoreCommand to send a (simple) SQL statement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx),

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for.